# touchBegan timestamp

Tags: iphone, box2d

In my game I need to calculate duration of touch. I did this by :

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  

self.endTime = [NSDate date];  //NSDate *endTime in .h
NSLog(@"%@",self.endTime); 

}  

-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{  
    tStart = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.endTime];  
    NSLog(@"duration %f",tStart);
```

I am using this time interval as a factor to calculate height of the jump the player makes.
Less is the tStart, low is the jump and more is the tStart, high is the jump. I am doing this as :

```
if(tStart/1000<=9.430)  
        {  
            [player jump:5.0f];  
        }  
        else if(tStart>9.430 && tStart<=9.470)  
        {  
            [player jump:7.0f];  
        }  
        else if(tStart/1000>9.470)  
        {  
            [player jump:8.0f];  
        }
```

However I want to perform this action on tochBegan so that player may jump as soon as screen is touched. For this need the value of tStart in touchBegan. How should I do that?

Thanks

Comment: so, basically you want to know how long the user held down his finger at the moment he or she touches the screen? ios is somewhat magical, but not *that* magical. you'll need to rethink your jumping mechanic, the most common way is to keep "boosting" the player for a while after jumping if the button (or touch) is still being held down. this is how most platformers do it.

Comment: :) But if you are saying that I can boost the player jump for a while if touch is still held down, there must be some way I can get to know, touch is still being held down. How can I find that?

Comment: Can GestureRecognizers help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given touch, the UITouch instance is the same, so at ccTouchBegan save the touch/touches with the oldest timestamp and then wait for ccTouchEnded. When you get the UITouch that you previously saved, it means the player lifted the finger.

**update**

You can

- Jump as soon as the user touches the screen.
- Jump and boost the jump while the touch is ongoing up to x milliseconds (suggestion from grapefrukt).
- Jump when the user releases the touch or a max time of x milliseconds has elapsed.
- Jump and boost the jump until the touch is over.

Option 4 is unpractical because the user can keep pressing as long as he wants. So given that you want to make a variable jump, here is code for option 3:

```
UITouch *jump = nil;

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    // no jump ongoing, start one
    if (jump==nil){
        jump = touch;
        // jump on a separate thread
        [NSThread performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)jump withObject:touch];
    }
}

-(void) jump:(UITouch*) touch {
    NSInterval time = [touch timestamp]; // I *think* this is the time since system uptime :P
    int jumpSpeed = 1;
    // increase the jump speed for every 100ms up to 'maxTimeYouAreAllowedToJump' ms
    while ( ([NSProcessInfo systemUptime]-time < maxTimeYouAreAllowedToJump) && (jump!=nil) ){
        jumpSpeed += 1;
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.1]; // sleep for 100ms
    }
    [self doTheJumpingWithSpeed:jumpSpeed]; // do the actual jump!
}

-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // user released the touch that initiated the jump
    if ((touch!=nil) && (touch==jump)) {
        jump =nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jano. But I need to perform the jump action in ccTouchBegan i.e before ccTouchEnded is called. Are you suggesting the same? A little explanation will be really useful :)

Comment: I implemented the above code and it works fine. But option 2 is the solution to my problem.i.e jump and boost while touch is ongoing.What should be done in that case?

Comment: Glad to hear. I guess jump: itself should paint the jumping and keep changing the coordinates until the maximum time is up or touch is nil. If this is box2d I don't know how it paints.

Comment: What do we mean by jump: itself should paint the jumping?

Comment: In the method jump: you have to draw on screen the character of your game and accelerate its speed for as long as the finger is pressed up to a max time. But I'm out of my depth when it comes to physics simulation.